# I am using jquery onbeforeunload function(). It show Dialog box when i Move to other Page If my dropdown list box Contains Values

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have not filled any text box in my Form then i need to move to other page but it Not Allowing me to Move because  i have values in Drop down list So when i Try to Move Other Page it is Not allowing me to Move..
it shows Dialog Box Are you want Move? So can i Avoid This Problem if I am having Values in Drop-down list.

This Following Code Works Fine If i am Not Having Drop down List in my page

```
 $(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
    if (formData != $('#formDivision').serialize() && !isSaved) {
        return 'There is unsaved data on the page, Are you sure u want to loose these changes.';
    }
});
```

Comment: which code you are using for redirect to other page?

Comment: formData must be different from current form data, assign formData when you got all data on form. I believe your dropdowns  get values later is that the case ?

Comment: In the Above mentioned Code I am Checking the from data if any entry are there in the Form.then not them to go other Page in between Else  if  data is not there Form serialize then i am allowing them to go other Page..

Comment: you can use `window.onbeforeunload = null;` to disable this message for some conditions.